# Unable to convert char array to decimal in the pig

Tags: apache-pig

Hi I am new to pig programming. I have one csv file and tab as a delimiter. In my price column I have lacs and crores. It looks like this `40.85 Lacs`, `36.73 Lacs`, `2.01 cr`. I want to convert into decimal like this

```
40.85 Lacs - 40,85,000
36.73 Lacs - 36,73,000
2.01 cr - 2,01,00000
```

I tried the following code:

```
a = LOAD '/user/user1/input/city/cityname.CSV' using PigStorage('|') as (SourceWebSite:chararray,PropertyID:chararray,ListedOn:chararray,ContactName:chararray,TotalViews:int,Price:chararray,PriceperArea:chararray,NoOfBedRooms:int,NoOfBathRooms:int,FloorNoOfProperty:chararray,TotalFloors:int,Possession:chararray,BuiltUpArea:chararray,Furnished:chararray,Ownership:chararray,NewResale:chararray,Facing:chararray,title:chararray,PropertyAddress:chararray,NearByFacilities:chararray,PropertyFeatures:chararray,Sellerinfo:chararray,Description:chararray);
DUMP a;
b = FOREACH a GENERATE Price;
dump b;
c = FILTER b BY (Price matches '.*Lacs.*');
d = FOREACH c GENERATE Price * 10000.0,SUBSTRING(Price,00000);
d = foreach c generate Price,TOKENIZE(REPLACE(Price,'.','')) AS e;
```

I am struggling for two days in this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You would have better chances of getting a good answer if you show what you have tried, maybe show us some code, where it does not work, maybe an error message,... ;-)

Comment: You cannot multiply a chararray (Price) with a number. First convert it to a numeric datatype (long or int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `REGEX_EXTRACT` to get the first part of the value, until the blank, cast it to BigDecimal and then multiply it. With this input data, for example:

```
(40.85 Lacs,1)
(36.73 Lacs,2)
(2.01 cr,3)
```

The following code would work:

```
A = load 'data' using PigStorage(';');
B = foreach A generate (bigdecimal)REGEX_EXTRACT($0, '(.*) (.*)', 1) * 1000000;
dump B;
```

And the output would be:

```
(40850000.00)
(36730000.00)
(2010000.00)
```

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to remove the dot

Comment: Sure, cast it to long or int.